# iOs 8 seems to be ignoring my UILabel's X and Y coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a somewhat old Objective C function that adds a UILabel to my UIView. It keeps track of the last label's Y in the variable _nextFieldY so it can put the next label below it. When I'm adding the label, I init it with its Width, Height, X and Y, and add it to my view. In iOs 7, this works, and correctly puts everything in its place. However, with any devices running the same app in iOs 8+, it appears the labels are all put at (0,0); the labels are all on top of each other in the top left corner. Was there a change between these versions that would cause this? I usually avoid programmatically adding things to my XIBs, so I don't know if there's certain work I have to do to get them to behave.

```
CGFloat labelWidth = 100;
CGFloat labelHeight = 40;
CGFloat labelY = _nextFieldY-REG_FORM_PADDING_Y;
UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];

UILabel *currLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(REG_FORM_OFFSET_X, labelY, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
currLabel.text = label;
[currLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[currLabel setFont:labelFont];

[currLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

[_formView addSubview:currLabel];

_nextFieldY += currLabel.frame.size.height + REG_FORM_PADDING_Y;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? To see if local variables are correctly incrementing?

Comment: My guess is that it's definitely something to do with AutoLayout- can you put breakpoints in the label and the in the console type `po currLabel.layer.frame`?

Comment: @sha I have. In both OS's the labelY property is correctly incrementing and is given to the labels in the initWithFrame call. If I use Reveal on the two versions, however, in iOs 7 the labels' Y is the same as what I set their Y to be, but in iOs 8 their Ys are all 0.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're setting the frame directly to position your view, you should be leaving `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `YES`.  Setting it to `NO` tells the system that it can ignore the frame you set.